# YouTube is insanely slow

Tags: internet-connection, youtube

I'm having issue from about a month with playing videos on YouTube. Sometimes everything is OK, but most of the time I'm not able to watch videos in more then 240p - 340p quality. While on other sites at the same moment I can play 1080p videos no problem there.

I've tried to switch to the HTML5 trial, uninstall and install Flash again, tried different browsers etc. When I try do download video using JDownloader it is insanely slow as well, like 150KB/s.

Comment: You may be getting throttled by your ISP.

Answer (score 3):

You will first want to figure out what server it is talking to receive that video; you can do this with `netstat` for instance, or use more advanced artillery like `wireshark`.

Once you have done that you can use `mtr` (or `pathping` on Windows, alternatively `WinMTR`) to do a trace route analysis. With this you can inspect at which hop the packets start dropping. And figure out whether it is your computer, your network, an intermediate hop or that YouTube server.

If only YouTube shows this problem, don't bother too much as it most likely does not lie with you computer; you can always try to verify with someone else using your ISP that lives very close near to you (to avoid him from having different hops). If you identify it is an intermediate hop, you can attempt to contact the person responsible for hosting that hop; the hop names often contain the company hosting them. If you only get an IP, you can try to do a reverse IP lookup.

Answer (score 1):

The servers supplied are really slow... I have a video downloading script installed and if I chose to download a video the first load, it downloads slow the first try about 80% of the time. I do a page refresh, download again, super speed. Basically youtube picks servers which are slow at first, one or two refreshes and it goes better.

Comment: Exactly same issue here. Insane slow, then refresh and super fast. How ever I had no issue like that when lived in Denmark... How to solve this crap?

Comment: Did some tries just now, it seems in most cases on the first try I get Google's own servers from San Francisco or Mountain View US while I'm from Romania. Reloading mostly gets me servers from Romtelecom or Artelecom from Bucharest and that's when I get good speeds. Unless there's a userscript or extension working to get proper URL's, from the user side there's not much to do about... maybe you could find a script or a coder on userscripts willing to do such a script.